# Vector Equality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Question: Suppose ⟨x, v⟩ = ⟨y, v⟩ for all v. Show that x and y must be the same vector.

I have not seen this explanation here yet, so I thought I would pose this question and offer a beginning answer to see if it is good enough and where it can be improved.

My answer: x = y iff ∀$x_i$ ∈ x and ∀$x_i$ ∈ y. However given that x ≠ y then there exists some $x_i$ that is not ∈ y and therefore ⟨x, v⟩ ≠ ⟨y, v⟩.

So, for ⟨x, v⟩ = ⟨y, v⟩, x = y

Comment: 'and therefore ⟨x, v⟩ ≠ ⟨y, v⟩' needs an explanation.

Comment: I'm more concerned with the use of $\in$ with respect to vectors. I'm guessing that $x_i \in x$ means that $x_i$ is one of the coordinates of $x$? If so, then your proof would implicitly assume that the vector space is $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$, otherwise this (already non-standard) notation would make no sense whatsoever. If you are assuming this, then I would advise using more standard notation ("If $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $y= (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$, but $x \neq y$, then $x_i \neq y_i$ for some $i$"), and also specify the vector $v$ that makes $\langle x ,v \rangle\neq\langle y,v\rangle$.

Comment: If $\langle x ,v \rangle = \langle y , v \rangle$ for all $v$, then $\langle x ,v \rangle - \langle y , v \rangle = 0$ for all $v$. Now can you see which $v$ might in particular be useful to consider?

Answer (score 2):

If the proposed relation holds, then you can take $v = x - y$, whence we get
\begin{align*}
\langle x,v\rangle = \langle y,v\rangle & \Rightarrow \langle x - y,v\rangle = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \langle x - y,x - y\rangle = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow x - y = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow x = y
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is an expansion of my comment above, since none of the answers are dealing with the presented proof.

Although how you've written your proof isn't exactly clear, it seems clear enough to me that your argument is supposed to say something like the following:

> Suppose $V = \Bbb{R}^n$ (or $\Bbb{C}^n$) and $x, y \in V$. Then $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ for some $x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n \in \Bbb{R}$ (or $\Bbb{C}$). If $x \neq y$, then $x_i \neq y_i$ for some $i$. If we let $v$ be the $i$th standard basis vector, i.e. $v$ has $0$ entries except for a $1$ in the $i$th position, then
> $$\langle x, v \rangle = x_i \neq y_i = \langle y, v \rangle.$$

This is a valid proof when $V = \Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$ under the standard inner products on these spaces. Your write-up suffers from at least two problems:

- It is not kosher to write $x_i \in x$, where $x$ is a vector and $x_i$ is the $i$th coordinate of $x$; this notation is reserved for sets. Here's some food for thought: if we consider $x = (1, -1)$ and $y = (-1, 1)$, then clearly $x \neq y$. But, is it not true that $a \in x \iff a \in y \iff a = \pm 1$? You can't determine whether these vectors are equal just by looking at what numbers appear in the entries.
- You cannot just claim that $\langle x, v \rangle \neq \langle y, v \rangle$, as this may not be true for various $v$. If $v = 0$, or indeed any vector that is orthogonal to $x - y$, then these quantities will be equal! Note that in the above write-up, I directly specify a $v$ that will make these inner products not equal.

So, if the exercise asks you for a proof in one of these two cases, then you're on the right track. However, if the exercise asks you for a proof in a general inner product space $V$ (which I suspect it does), then your argument falls apart.

We may no longer specify a "standard" basis. Indeed, we may not have a (finite) basis at all! We can't identify any standard coordinates, and decide whether vectors are not equal based upon them, nor can we find a standard basis vector $v$ that makes their inner products disagree. With a fair bit more work, you can talk about orthonormal bases (for many inner product spaces), and then push this argument through. However, it's far better to follow the suggestions of jl00 and user0102: you need an elementary, coordinate-free approach, just using the axioms of inner product spaces.

Answer (score 0):

**Inner product definition**

The inner product $\langle·,·\rangle$ for a vector space satisfies the following four properties. Let $u$, $v$, and $w$ be vectors and $\alpha$ be a scalar, then:

1. $\langle u+v,w\rangle =\langle u,w\rangle +\langle v,w\rangle$
2. $\langle \alpha v,w\rangle =\alpha\langle v,w\rangle$
3. $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle w,v\rangle$
4. $\langle v,v\rangle=0$ and equal if and only if $v=0$

Note that some authors define an inner product to be a function $\langle ·,·\rangle$ satisfying only the first three of the above conditions with the added (weaker) condition of being (weakly) non-degenerate i.e. if $ \langle v,w\rangle=0$ for all $w$, then $v=0$. Note that to go from the strong property to the weak property is easy, you just choose $w=v$ since you can choose any $w$.

**Application to given problem**

Suppose $\langle x, v\rangle = \langle y, v\rangle$ for all $v$. This means that:
$$\langle x,v\rangle-\langle y,v\rangle=0$$
$$\langle x-y,v\rangle=0$$
for all $v$. According to the 4th property of the inner product definition, this also means $x-y=0$ then $x=y$.